# Chrome blocking local file upload

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am having trouble linking the D3 library. I have created a local server using python, but nevertheless Chrome continues to say that it can not load local files. Is it a problem with my code, or is there another issue? I have tried using the localhost on Firefox and IE to no avail.

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Тестовая диаграмма</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='file:/c:/Users/John/Documents/HTML_project_files/d3/d3.v3.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var dataset = [5,20,10,13,50];
            var w = 500;
            var h = 100;
            var barpad = 1;
            var svg = d3.select('body')
                        .append('svg')
                        .attr({
                                width: w,
                                height: h
                        });
            svg.selectAll('rect')
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append('rect')
               .attr({
                    x: function(d, i) { return i * (w/dataset.length);},
                    y: function(d) { return h - (d * 2);},
                    width: w / dataset.length - barpad,
                    height: function(d) { return d * 4;}
                });
            svg.selectAll('text')
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append('text')
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
               })
               .attr({
                    x: function(d,i) { return i * (w/dataset.length) + (w/ dataset.length - barpad) / 2;},
                    y: function(d) { return h - (d * 2) + 15;},
                    'font-family': "serif",
                    'font-size': "11px",
                    'fill': "white",
                    'text-anchor': "middle"
               });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of the chrome's default security settings. Read more [here](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/).

To resolve it you have 2 options,

1) Load the JS file from a CDN

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.10/d3.js'></script>
```

2) User relative path. 
if you are working in the HTML_project_files foolder the you can do

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='d3/d3.v3.js'></script>
```

If you want to go one level up. then you can do

`src='../d3/d3.v3.js'` so and so..

Comment: :D I have had this issue in the beginning of my learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are running chrome with enabled web security.

Instead of

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='file:/c:/Users/John/Documents/HTML_project_files/d3/d3.v3.js'></script>
```

Do like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.10/d3.js'></script>
```